# VBA Excel Macro to subtract cell from different sheet using VLOOKUP

Tags: vba, excel

I'm try to write a macro that will auto update stock by taking the ammount used from one cell, subtracting it from a total in a different sheet.

Sheet view:

[image]

So in this instance - I want to subtract "kgs" which is cell range 'I17:I24' from what is "kgs available" which is held in the sheet "Malt" and updated from a VLOOKUP defined from the "Batch Code" in the Brew Sheet.

I'm guessing the code would probably have to VLOOKUP that batch code in the Malt sheet and subtract the "kgs" in the "Brew Sheet" sheet from the "kgs available" in the "Malt" sheet (Column L)

What also might contribute complications is if the cells in range E17:24, which contain the Batch Codes for the VLOOKUP have no values. Would that throw up errors, if though I may not need to use all of the cells in that range? (If that makes sense - sometimes, I may only need to use 1/2 of the 8 cells in the range)

Apologises in advance if my question is vague. My coding knowledge is very limited.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

you need to get the sum of KGs in range E17:24 where the batch code matched the batch code on the malt sheet

```
=sumif(Malt!$E$17:$E$24,L17,Malt!$I$17:$I$24)
```

Then all you need to do is subtract that from the available value in column I

```
=I17-sumif(Malt!$E$17:$E$24,L17,Malt!$I$17:$I$24)
```

Not sure if I have the columns correct.

Comment: It's not the sum I need subtracting, it's the individual amount from each cell in that range to the corresponding batch code in the different sheet - which is then subtracted when the macro button is hit.

Comment: My solutions assumes that it's possible to have multiple entries for each batch code and therefore would need to get the sum of all the 16-PILS entries for example.  I was not suggesting that you sum values that have different batch codes.  If you think that your vlookup will return an error then you can use =iferror(vlookup,"") to catch the error.

Comment: That would be possible but I probably wouldn't be having multiple entries of each batch code. I've already started coding a macro that exports the data from this sheet in to a new separate worksheet and resets the data.